# Why is compareTo red?

Tags: java, android

I have an healthplanArray consisting of Healthplan objects. They have a primitive int called hour and I use a setter-getter namely getHour() to call that int.

Now I need to sort the array list but compareTo is red in Android Studio. My function is this:

```
private void sortHealthplan() {
        Collections.sort(healthplanArrayList, (o1, o2) -> o1.getHour().compareTo(o2.getHour()));
    }
```

Any idea what could be causing this? What information should I post here? Is there a class I need to import?

Comment: `int` does not have a `compareTo()` method.

Comment: What would I return then if I wanted to sort in ascending order?

Comment: See [`Integer#compare(int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,int)). Or if you're not worried about overflow/underflow then you can simply subtract one from the other and return the result.

Comment: Or, [the Android version of `Integer.compare()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer#compare(int,%20int))

Comment: Or `Comparator.comparingInt(HealthPlan::getHour)`